# JQuery Multiple AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Please refer the code below,
I already set both of the ajax as async : false.
I found out that when the function calling doUpdate2ndAJAX(), the program start executing $(".search").click(); even though doUpdate2ndAJAX() not yet finish executing.

In short current situation:
1. doUpdate2ndAJAX() execute
2. doUpdate2ndAJAX() not yet finish, start execute $(".search").click()
3. doUpdate2ndAJAX() Finish execute and response back

May I know how can I make it as 
1. doUpdate2ndAJAX() execute
2. doUpdate2ndAJAX() Finish execute and response back
3. call $(".search").click();

[ Execute in sequence order ]

Thanks.
-fsloke

```
firstCalled: function() {
             $.ajax({                          
            url: "XXX",
            async: false,
            success: function(response) {

                        doUpdate2ndAJAX();

                        $(".search").click();

                        }
           });
}               

function  doUpdate2ndAJAX(){
              $.ajax({                         
            url: "YYY",
            async: false,
            success: function(response) {
                            // UPDATE SOMETHING
                        }
               });
              return false;
}
```

Comment: Do not use `async: false`.  It will completely freeze the browser until the server replies.

Comment: Yes, SLaks. I want the browser to Freeze. So that the ajax call will be in sequence as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use Deferred objects, those are objects to manipulate async calls, you can solve :

```
$.when($.ajax("/page1.php"), $.ajax("/page2.php"))
  .then(myFunc, myFailure);
```

This way myFunc executes after the 2 ajax calls are made, and myFailure if either one has an error.

You can read more about it in the jquery official documentation:[`JQuery Deferred Object`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

Answer (score 0):

You should make the AJAX calls asynchronous, and call `$(".search").click();` in the `success` callback for the second request.

Depending on your structure, you may want to add a parameter to `doUpdate2ndAJAX` which tells it whether to call `$(".search").click();`.
Alternatively, you can add a callback parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the "complete" callback to invoke the $(".search").click().

You can see the differences between success and complete callbacks here:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: "complete" call back does not work in my case. Thanks Fabrizio.